# Not printing the compared character in c, doubly linked list

Tags: c, list, printing, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

The problem statement is as follows

> Insert a list of names and display the strings starting with letter ‘B’.

My display function

```
{
  ND *temp=start;
  if(temp==NULL)
  {
    printf("LIST is empty");
    return;
  }
  printf("\n list : \t" );
  printf("%s",temp->data[0]);
  while(temp->next!=NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(temp->data[0],'b')==0)
    {
    printf(" %s ->",temp->data[size]);
    }
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  
}
```

The compiler is showing a warning `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`
And if i change `'b'` in the strcmp function by `"b"`. This warning will not appear but, in both the cases it is not printing the output. Can anyone help me with this?

All the required libraries are included.
Thank you.

Comment: Assuming that `temp->data` is an array of characters (or a pointer to the first element of such an array) then what is `temp->data[0]`? Is it really a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string (of type `char *`) which is what the `%s` format expects?

Comment: Also, `temp->data[size]`? Where does `size` come from? What is its value?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude size is defined as 100, this is linked list, the temp->data is pointing to the first node, temp->data[0] will access the first character of the string(My assumption)(I thought this was correct).

Comment: A few things: The `str` prefix in `strcmp` means it's for *strings* not characters. To compare characters you compare them using `==` (a `char` is a basically just a small integer). A single character should be printed using the `%c` format. And yes if `temp->data` is a string then the first character is `temp->data[0]` and *not* `temp->data[size]`. And `temp->data[size]` is *out of bounds* if there's only `size` elements in the array.

Comment: Yeah!, i got that output. Was missing somethings. Thanks.